# vBulletin To bbPress Conversion - How Can I Redirect The Old URLs To The New Ones?

Tags: .htaccess, vbulletin, data-conversion, bbpress

I converted my vbulletin forum to bbpress and everything works fine except the redirection of the old urls part.

I want to redirect old vbulletin urls to the new bbpress ones using .htaccess but i have no idea how to do it. I’m still new to URL redirection.

**Old vBulletin URL:**

http://www.forum.site.com/showthread.php?80-post-title

**New bbPress URL:**

http://www.site.com/forums/topic/post-title

Can anyone help me? I would really appreciate it.

UPDATED: Here are the contents of my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[0-9]+-([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/?showthread\.php$ http://www.site.com/forums/topic/%1 [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

# handles http redirect

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum\.site\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.site.com/discussions [R=301,L,QSA,NE]

# handles https redirect
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum\.site\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.site.com/discussions [R=301,L,QSA,NE]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the document root of the **www.forum.site.com** domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[0-9]+-([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/?showthread\.php$ http://www.site.com/forums/topic/%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but it's still not how i want it. I want to redirect all the vbulletin URLs to the new bbPress ones (which works great with the rules you posted) but i also want all the other vbulletin URLs(homepage, member profiles, forums, and all the other urls) to be redirected to the bbPress homepage.

Comment: one thing i forgot to mention. i currently use a htaccess code to redirect all the urls from http://forum.site.com to http://site.com/forums . How can i make my code work with yours?

Comment: @AllenPayne If you're redirecting `forum.site.com` **to** `site.com/forums` then that rule should be **after** the one above. As for all those other cases, you'll just need to deal with them on a case by case basis, that scope is outside of the question that you've asked (and would be impossible to ask and answer within comments)

Comment: i tried placing your rules first but it still not working. when i go to http://www.forum.site.com/showthread.php?80-post-title it redirects me to http://www.site.com . i just updated the first post with the current contents of my .htaccess file so you can take a look.

Comment: Nevermind. It's working now. I was editing the htaccess file with my FTP program and i started to test if the rules work before saving the file. :)) Thanks a lot for your help.